# Header disappearing along with slideshow

Tags: html, css, header, slideshow

My webpage includes a header and a slideshow below it. My slideshow images fade in and out, and they all have a height of 100vh, and with the header on top, the space they take altogether goes beyond the size of the page view and thus there's a scrollbar. I don't want a scrollbar, I want everything to be on the same page, so I put an absolute position on the header. That's when the problem starts. Although the header is now in front of the slideshow, and everything is in the same page view, the header fades in and out along with the slides. Now, this only happens if the header is in an absolute or fixed position. If I put the position to relative or even get rid of the position, it's fine, but not everything is on the same page anymore.

Here's the HTML:

```
<header>

  <div class="container header">

    <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="images/logo2.png"></a>

    <nav class="header-nav">

      <ul class="header-navlist">

        <li><a href="">Home</a><li>
        <li><a href="">Works</a><li>
        <li><a href="">About</a><li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a><li>

      </ul>

    </nav>

  </div>

</header>

<section class="welcome-page">

  <div class="container welcome">

    <h1 class="greeting">Welcome</h1>

  </div>

</section>

<div class="slideshow">

  <div class="slideshow-item one">

  </div>

  <div class="slideshow-item two">

  </div>

  <div class="slideshow-item three">

  </div>

  <div class="slideshow-item four">

  </div>

</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: black;
 position: absolute;
}

.container {
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
}

.logo {
 height: 54px;
 width: 100px;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 3px;
}

nav {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
 /* color: #C0C0C0; */
 font-weight: bold;
}

.header-nav {
 float: right;
}

.header-navlist {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
}

.header-navlist li {
 padding: 18px 7px 7px 0;
}

.welcome-page {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: absolute;
}

.welcome {
 height: inherit;
 text-align: center;
}

.greeting {
 color: white;
 font-size: 4em;
 position: relative;
 top: 30%;
}

.slideshow {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow-item {
 width: inherit;
 height: inherit;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 animation: cycleImages 31s infinite;
}

.one {
 background-image: url("images/artwork/image1.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
}

.two {
 background-image: url("images/artwork/image2.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
}

.three {
 background-image: url("images/artwork/image3.jpg");
}

@keyframes cycleImages {
 25% {
   opacity: 1;
 }
 40% {
   opacity: 0;
 }
}

.slideshow-item:nth-child(1) {
 animation-delay: 0s;
}

.slideshow-item:nth-child(2) {
 animation-delay: 10s;
}

.slideshow-item:nth-child(3) {
 animation-delay: 20s;
}
```

I also want the word "welcome" to appear in front to the slides. I want to be static, the same for all the slides and not fading in and out along with the images. What I've done is create a separate section set to a height of 100vh, with the word "welcome" in the middle. I want it to be in front of the slides, so I set the position to absolute, but it doesn't show up.

Comment: `overflow-x:hidden;` will hide the x axis scroll bar. You may also try a reset on padding and margin for everything.

Comment: I tried the overflow-x:hidden. I've tried putting it in the slides selector, then the body selector, but the scrollbar still won't disappear.

Comment: Have you also tried doing a margin and padding reset? This may and will likely cause some issues with your layout but its worth a try to see if browser dependent margin and/or padding is causing the overflow. `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` try placing that reset in the top of your CSS file and see if that resolves the overflow.